# What does Hot Boot mean?

Tags: reboot, miui

In Miui ROMs, there are four options for rebooting a phone from the power menu:

[image: Miui Reboot Options]

What does "Hot Boot" mean, technically speaking? Are there any circumstances where a hot boot could cause harm? Are there any reasons for choosing to hot boot at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it works like other "hot boot" apps and functions, then it basically restarts the Android GUI processes/threads. There was an [XDA news post a while](http://www.xda-developers.com/windows-mobile/reboot-the-shell-only-with-hot-reboot-for-android/) back after someone made an app for it where the app author described it as such:

> Hot reboot by rebooting only the graphical Android shell.

From what I know it's sort of equivalent to restarting your X server in a Linux environment (like hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, for example). I would definitely doubt that you'd cause any damage by restarting your graphical environment, especially considering other OSes do this pretty easily, but I suppose there's an outside chance if MIUI implements it strangely.

Typically the reason people use a "hot boot" option is if the UI has somehow gotten sluggish and would benefit from a restart but they want to save time by not restarting the whole system (maybe a memory leak in the UI or something of that sort). It could also be useful if you need to restart the UI to apply some sort of change, like a theme perhaps.